esxi virtual machine ’s storage usage exceed 30% than it was allocated
We allocated 0.2 + 10.98 T but the storage usage shows it use 14T why？
2 disks are both “Thin provisioned”



Do you have any snapshots?


Thin-provisioned vmdks may grow up to their maximum size when written to. They're just not fully grown from the start. Deleting data does not usually shrink a vmdk.
Each snapshot might grow up to the provisioned size of the VM, doubling, trippling, etc the required potential amount of storage.
Full-state snapshots also include the VM's memory.

To reclaim space from snapshots, remove and consolidate them. To reclaim space from deleted guest files in a thin-provisioned vmdk, you need to either

make sure empty disk space is zeroed - writing zeros to empty blocks grows a vmdk to provisioned size though - and then use vmkfstools to release the zeroed space (Details)
use a storage and guest OS that supports releasing guest-deleted space via unmap (Details)


should the maxsize of Thin-provisioned vmdks  is 0.2 + 10.98 T in this case?

Deleting data does not shrink a vmdk — what if I run fstrim or blkdiscard (issue SCSI UNMAP / ATA TRIM) within the VM? qcow2 does shrink in this case (strictly speaking, it becomes sparse but that still releases the space). VMWare's vSAN is documented to release space too.

@NikitaKipriyanov Agreed, there are some scenarios where space could be released - qemu is not discussed here and vSAN requires specific enabling though. I don't think that applies here, as the OP is asking.

Accoding the Detail  it will recyle the deleted partition, not the typical kind of “shrink” --- resize size partition
